# Should share udp socket resource between threads to send/receive messages in php

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, resources, share

I am working on a network communication application.

For the communication I used two threads one for sending another for receiving. Both the threads uses the same socket resource shared between them. I tested with bulk message traffic both send and receive. After a random minutes the script running terminal show some error "PHP Warning: Supplied invalid socket resource".

**1. Can simultaneous access possible to socket between threads?
2. Any expiration time for created socket**

**Server system configuration**

- CentOS 7.4
- PHP 7.2 thread enabled
- Pthread 3